# How can I get text from a text field with an applescript xcode project

Tags: xcode, applescript

I am trying to write an xcode app with applescript. I need to get user inputed text from a text box and set is as a variable when the submit button is pressed.

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

I too am just getting to grips with Cocoa-Applescript (and there's not all that much info around!) but it should work as follows, at least this is how I've done it in my app :)

**1) Create an outlet for the text field:**

i.e. underneath:

```
 script AppDelegate
     property parent : class "NSObject"
```

add:

```
     property myTextField : missing value
```

The 'missing value' bit is what makes myTextField available in Interface Builder.

**2) Create a handler for your button:**

```
 on submitButtonClicked_(sender)

 end submitButtonClicked_
```

(name it anything you like, but as far as I know it has to start with a lowercase letter and end with an underscore)

**3) Link the handler and outlet to their respective UI elements:**

- In Interface Builder, right-click the App Delegate, and drag the circle next to submitButtonClicked onto your button
- Likewise drag the circle from myTextField to the text field

**4) Add a line in the click handler to set a variable to the value of the field:**

```
 on submitButtonClicked_(sender)

     set currentTextFieldText to myTextField's stringValue() as text

     -- do stuff with currentTextFieldText

 end submitButtonClicked_
```

And if you wanted to put something in the text field:

```
 tell myTextField to setStringValue_(whatYouWantInTheField)
```

Hope this helps!